# Where do XAML files that build as "Page" go?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I've added a XAML file to a Windows Phone 8 project. Its build action is "Page". I want to load the XAML as a text string (to feed into `XamlReader.Load()`). How can I accomplish this?

It's not available as a separate file in the XAP package; it's probably somewhere in the DLL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When set to `Page`, the compiler will compile the XAML into BAML and add the BAML file as a resource to the assembly.

If you wish to get the original XAML back out from the BAML resource at runtime, then you will need to deserialize the BAML, and then serialize your object to XAML.

You can have a look at the [Baml2006Reader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.baml2006.baml2006reader.aspx), or a better option would be to use `Application.LoadComponent` which is what the `InitializeComponent` method uses internally. `InitializeComponent` is called by the partially generated class for your XAML code behind.

```
var uri = new Uri("/MyAppName;component/MyXaml.xaml", //Note extension: XAML, not BAML
     UriKind.Relative);
Page rootObject = new Page(); //Assuming XAML root element is Page - it could be anything
Application.LoadComponent(rootObject, uri);
```

(assuming the root element of your XAML file is a `Page`).

You can then serialize the `Page` to a XAML string using the `XamlWriter`:

```
string xaml = XamlWriter.Save(rootObject);
```

Note that this is the `XamlWriter` in the `System.Windows.Markup` namespace, not `System.Xaml`. If your XAML has WPF types, then you should use this `XamlWriter` to avoid errors.

Comment: Fixed the snippet somewhat, tx.